# Duplicates in a LEFT JOIN

Tags: duplicates, left-join, max, no-duplicates

I am using LEFT JOIN to join two tables but it is returning a few duplicates.  This is my query:

```
SELECT tblDrill.Hole_ID, tblAssay.MidPoint, tblAssay.SampleNumber, tblAssay.Gold, tblMagSus.MagSus
FROM tblDrill LEFT JOIN tblMagSus ON (((tblAssay.MidPoint)>tblMagSus.From And (tblAssay.MidPoint)<tblMagSus.To)) AND (tblAssay.Hole_ID = tblMagSus.Hole_ID);
```

A few times, there is more than one tblAssay.MidPoint that falls between the tblMagSus.From and tblMagSus.To so it returns two records. I only want it to return the record that contains the highest MagSus value.

Comment: Could you clarify what you are querying the database for and what is stored in each table?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps SELECT DISTINCT would be appropriate

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

```
SELECT DISTINCT tblDrill.Hole_ID, tblAssay.MidPoint, tblAssay.SampleNumber, tblAssay.Gold, tblMagSus.MagSus
FROM tblDrill LEFT JOIN tblMagSus ON (((tblAssay.MidPoint)>tblMagSus.From And (tblAssay.MidPoint)<tblMagSus.To)) AND (tblAssay.Hole_ID = tblMagSus.Hole_ID);
```

Comment: I have tried the SELECT DISTINCT option but I far as I understand, SELECT DISTINCT identifies entire rows that are distinct and I am looking for just tblDrill.SampleNumber that are distinct.